# Understanding a complex query using :last selector

Tags: jquery

hey guys i am using the :last selector in one of my small tiny plugins , just wanted to ask a small question :

given the following markup :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
     <li class="active"><a href="#sectionA">Section A</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#sectionB">Section B</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#sectionC">Section C</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

if i make the following selection :

```
 var $previous = $('ul').find('.active:last a');
```

am i saying ,

1. go inside the .active class and select the last occuring `<a>` or
2. am i saying  find the last occuring .active class and find the `<a>` inside it ??

i have console logged and done a few tests but just wanted to confirm , as the :last selector is pritty confusing .

Answer (score 1):

You are looking inside the last element with the `active` class for all anchor tags.

In order to select the last anchor within the `active` class you would need

`$('.active a:last');`

Or, for the last `active` class

`$('.active:last a:last');`

Answer (score 0):

It is the last occurring .active LI element inside the UL (and then the links within that).
If you want to go within .active you'd put a space after active and change the bit afterwards to make sense, but I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: It wouldn't return the first link. You would get all anchor tags within the selector.

Comment: Yes that's true, I'll fix.